# Given two sets having number of elements a , b respectively .Any subset can have 2 elements from A and 1 from B or vice versa

Tags: algorithm, math, set

We need to find the all possible subsets assuming the element used will be deleted.

test case
a=4 b=5

- a b b
- a b b
- a a b

hence the answer is 3

Is there a general formula for doing this?

Comment: Isn´t the answer the same for all cases where a and b > 1?

Comment: no it will differ in every case as we have two choices in each step

Comment: It is very unclear why with a = 4 and b = 5 that is the result, from your title it seems just count number of subsets picking 2 values from A and 1 from B or viceversa

Comment: What is solution for 2/7 case?

Comment: I think I understand now, isn´t the answer min(a, b, floor((a + b) / 3)) ?

Comment: thanks that solved the question Can you explain how you reached it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a = x and b = z. If we want to maximize the amount of groups we can make, we will want to pick 2 from the letter that we have most of. Let's say z > x. While this holds true, we will want to pick 2 from z and 1 from x.

Eventually 2 things can happen: either x got to 0, in which case we made x groups in total or x = z. If x = z, we can alternate taking 2 from one and 1 from the other until either both are 1 or both are 0. If both are 0, that means we used all z + x letters, so we made (z + x) / 3 groups. If both are 1, we used (z + x - 2) letters, so we made (z + x - 2 / 3) groups. Both these cases can be handled by floor((x + z) / 3).

So we have min(x, floor((x + z) / 3)) and if you assume x > z, you will also have to consider that x never got equal to z so you made z groups, thus leaving us with min(x, z, floor((x + z) / 3))